# jQuery Mobile: How can I link to an external page without breaking web app view?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I created a web app (without browser chrome) which loads most of its pages locally from index.html. Now I have one page which i can not integrate into index.html, since it has to be refreshed when loaded. I placed it on the same server and called it stats.html and link to it like this:

```
<a href="stats.html" data-role="button" rel="external">Stats</a>
```

When I click this link, the browser pops to the front instead switching to the page without browser chrome.

How can I link to an external page in a way that it still looks like one app?

I appreciate any hints to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

just found https://github.com/mrmoses/jQuery.stayInWebApp that seems to be the solution.

Comment: This works great... In my case, I wanted to keep the user even if it was a full link with http://, so I just commented the `if(!dest.match(/^http(s?)/g)) {` line...